# How do I make my Discord.js (Commando) bot leave servers (on join) if the GuildIDs aren't whitelisted in my code?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I have a bot that requires a paid subscription. I want to be able to whitelist specific guild IDs in my code that the customer wants. How would I go about doing this? It would spontaneously leave each server it joins unless it's whitelisted in my code. I've already tried something.

```
client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {

  let premiumServers = ['ID1', 'ID2']; // Obviously I replaced ID1, ID2 etc with actual guild IDs
  let Premium = true;
  for (var i in premiumServers) {
    if (guild.id !== premiumServers[i]) Premium = false;
  }

  if(Premium = false) {
    guild.leave();
  }

});
```

There weren't any error messages. What should happen is the bot would leave any server its invited to unless the server ID is on the whitelist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would look clean and do the best Job:

```
let premiumServers = ['ID1', 'ID2'];
client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
    if(!premiumServers.includes(guild.id)) return guild.leave();
});
```

Your Bot would still be able to join Servers while its crashed/offline without leaving them so consider using:

```
const premiumServers = ['ID1', 'ID2'];

client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
    if(!premiumServers.includes(guild.id)) return guild.leave();
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
        if(!premiumServers.incudes(guild.id)) guild.leave();
    });
    console.log(`${client.user.username} is now online...`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop sets `Premium` to false if the guild's ID does not match **all** of the array of IDs in the `premiumServer`.

What you probably want to do is to set `Premium` to true if the guild's ID matches **any** of the array of IDs.
Like so:

```
// Assume that the guild is not premium first.
let Premium = false;
for (var i in premiumServers) {
  // Check if the guild is premium
  if (guild.id == premiumServers[i]) {
    // Set to true and stop the loop.
    Premium = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Finally, you did an assignment in the `if` statement, not an equality test.

```
if(Premium = false) // <-- the statement inside does an assignment
{
  guild.leave();
}
```

Use `Premium == false` or `!Premium` instead.